Is there a way to change the colour of the note marker inside a talltblr from the tabularray package? (+ 2 related subquestions)
I have a table I am making using the tabularray package.
Main question:
Is there a way to change the colour of the marker that is put inside the table cell? Currently in texstudio it is shown in red hyperlink formatting as shown on the figure underneath. I have to compile my text in texstudio as overleaf times out.
Subquestion 1 (answered in the comments):
When I made the MWE underneath in overleaf it was not formatted in red any more and I could also not click on the "a" any more as if it was a hyperlink. I would like to know why there is a different result between texstudio and overleaf?
Subquestion 2 (answered in the comments):
Using the talltblr command is the only way to use footnotes with the tabularray package right? If I understand the documentation right you cannot have notes with the regular tblr command?
MWE (edit to add the hyperref package):
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{talltblr}
  [  note{a} = {note},
  ]
  {
    colspec = {X[c]},
    stretch = 0,
    rowsep = 6pt,
    vlines,
    hlines,
  }
  \TblrNote{a} \\
\end{talltblr}

\end{document}


Edit based on the comments:
I tried to add a command that changes the hyperlink colour to black, but that of course changes all the hyperlinks in my document while I only want the notes in my table in black. I tried to define a command that changes the hyperlink colour like this \newcommand{\changeurlcolor}[1]{\hypersetup{urlcolor=#1}} from here. I put this command with the argument "black" before the table declaration and then with "red" behind it with the goal of only changing the colour for this table. But that did not seem to work as the notes in the table stayed red.

Regarding your subquestions, you are missing hyperref package to get clickable links, and yes, table and cell notes are only supported in tall and long tblr environments.

@Mane32 Ah interesting, this means that tabularray makes the notes as hyperlinks. See my edit for more information

I think I found the solution myself and added it.

The tabularray notes inside a talltblr make use of the hyperref package. From that package it specifically uses the colour option to format links: linkcolor.
By adding a new command you can change that option before and after the talltblr so the notes inside have the specific colour you prefer:
\newcommand{\changeurlcolor}[1]{\hypersetup{linkcolor=#1}}
To make them black for example you would use \changeurlcolor{black} before the talltblr and you can change back to the default colour by putting \changeurlcolor{red} after the talltblr.
The MWE would look like this:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcommand{\changeurlcolor}[1]{\hypersetup{linkcolor=#1}}

\begin{document}

\changeurlcolor{black}
\begin{talltblr}
  [  note{a} = {note},
  ]
  {
    colspec = {X[c]},
    stretch = 0,
    rowsep = 6pt,
    vlines,
    hlines,
  }
  \TblrNote{a} \\
\end{talltblr}
\changeurlcolor{red}

\end{document}

